# bash: How do I write a shell script to sftp a mongodump from a MongoDB Docker container inside a DigitalOcean droplet to backup the MongoDB database?

Tags: bash, mongodb, meteor, docker, sftp

I'm running a MeteorJS webapp deployed with meteor-up on a DO droplet. I would like to have a .sh run from my local machine to get backups occasionally. Folders being able to have timestamps would be a plus.

This is what I am trying to achieve with a single .sh file:

on local machine:

```
ssh root@my.droplet.address
# <prompt for password>
```

inside droplet:

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

in mongodb docker:

```
rm -rf dump
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 -d app
```

on remote droplet:

```
rm -rf dump
docker cp mongodb:/dump dump
```

on local machine:

```
sftp root@my.droplet.address
```

in remote droplet (sftp):

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S`
get -r dump $DATE
```

Is it possible to get all these in one .sh file?

Comment: It's probably possible to make all of those things happen through a shell script. What is your actual question here? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for a script that i can run once, get prompted for the ssh password, and get the mongodump files on my local machine.

Comment: what do you want to achieve  "get -r dump $DATE"? sftp get -r copies a directory and all its contents.

Comment: mongodump dumps json and bson files in a folder named dump, I want to have them on my local machine. $date would be the directory on the local machine, named according to the time. I've found a solution that works for me in my answer below, but using scp instead of sftp.

Answer (score 1):

In the script you can run the commands in the following way:

```
ssh root@my.droplet.address "docker exec mongodb rm -rf dump && docker exec mongodb mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 -d app && rm -rf dump && docker cp mongodb:/dump dump && docker cp mongodb:/dump dump"

ssh root@my.droplet.address:/dump $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S) >/dev/null 2
```

Comment: Thank you, first line worked great, but in the second line I had problems with dd: unrecognized operand '2'. With some additional searching online I found a solution with `scp`, I'll have my answer up soon

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to do it with one .sh file. Without ssh keys, this will prompt you twice for the root password. the dump folder will be copied to ./$DATE. where $DATE = current datetime on the local machine.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S`
ssh root@cleanr.ivanho.me "docker exec mongodb rm -rf dump && docker exec mongodb mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 -d app && rm -rf dump && docker cp mongodb:/dump dump"

scp -r root@cleanr.ivanho.me:/root/dump $DATE
```